# Нужно ли в json ставить кавычки для имён ключей?

Tags: json

```
{
    backet: {

        apples: 2,
        cats: 3

    }
}
```

Сервис https://jsonlint.com/ считает этот код неверным и выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
{   backet: {       apples:
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

Как сделать так, чтобы код стал безошибочным для этого сервиса?

Comment: В json ключи нужно обрамлять в кавычки: `"backet"`. Но есть разновидности формата, например, json5 - в нём можно писать без кавычек. Естественно, для работы с ним нужно использовать соответствующий парсер и пр.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json - это строка и от вас ждут строку, должно быть так:

```html
{
  "backet": {
      "apples": "2",
      "cats": "3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Но ключи и объекты разве пишутся с кавычками?

Comment: В json обязательно, причём именно в двойных

Comment: посреди кода на javascript можно писать без кавычек;
т. к. код на javascript читает и превращает в объект интерпретатор javascript;
а json читает и превращает в объект json-парсер;
объект получается в итоге одинаковый

Comment: @Sergei Kirjanov вопрос о json

Comment: @Aleksandr конечно; вот я и уточнил, что в json кавычки нужны, т. к. это не javascript